# Merging between streams in Perforce using Command line rather than P4V

Tags: perforce, branching-and-merging, p4v, perforce-integrate, perforce-stream

I need to merge the streams using commands in P4. can anyone help me with this? the two streams are parent child streams. I need to merge down from parent to child.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to do this on the command line? Or are you trying to figure out how to do this using P4V? Your question title says one thing, your question content says the other.

Comment: Sry about that, Changed the Title. I want to merge the streams using commandline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm typing this from memory, without actually trying it, but I think this is pretty close:

1. Switch your client workspace to the child stream, since that is the target of the merge: `p4 client -s -S child`
2. Sync your client, to make sure you're building and testing with the latest files: `p4 sync`
3. Merge the parent stream's changes into your child stream: `p4 merge`
4. Resolve any conflicts: `p4 resolve`
5. Build and test, to confirm that you're happy with the results
6. Submit the merged code to the child stream: `p4 submit`

Of course, make sure that you're working with the correct client workspace, as the correct user, etc., by running `p4 set` before you start this process, to look at your P4CLIENT, P4USER, etc. settings.